# How to set background-color for alternate rows in iterated dynamic table

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a dynamic table as follow in JSP:

```
 <TABLE id="tableCount">
      <TR>
        <TH>Count</TH>
        <TH>Part</TH>
        <TH>device</TH>
      </TR>


 <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${data1.getCount().size() - 1}">
       <TR>
               <TD>
                    ${data1.getCount().get(i)}
               </TD>
               <TD>
                    ${data1.getPart().get(i)}
               </TD>
               <TD>
                    ${data1.getDevice().get(i)}
               </TD>
     </TR>
</c:forEach>
 </TABLE>
```

I wanted to have alternate `rows` as different `background-color`, but I am not sure how to do that with the iterative dynamic table.

I tried to do this using `CSS` though which is as follow:

```
#tableCount tr.alt td{
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#880000;
}
```

But not able to get what I want. Any help on this would be really great.Do we need to use JQuery or any scripting language to achieve this goal?? Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this with CSS. Use `:nth-of-type(2n+2)` to target every other row

```
#tableCount tr td:nth-of-type(2n+2){
   //styles here
}
```

You could also do `:nth-of-type(even)`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ry3Pc/)

**UPDATE**

Ok if you want to target rows instead of columns just add that to the `tr` instead of `td`

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ry3Pc/1/)

Comment: Thank you jmore, but its doing the alternate columns, I needed to target the rows. I was able to style the alternate column but not able to style the rows? can you please suggest on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with css

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: green}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: red}
```